# Installing MS Office 2010 updates in PlayOnLinux/Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

Is there an easy way to keep MS Office updated on PlayOnLinux?

I am running MS Office (2010) on PlayOnLinux (4.2.10) on Ubuntu 16.04. I was able to install the latest service pack (SP2) by manually downloading it and installing by

- POL->Configure->select the correct virtual drive->Miscellaneous->Run a .exe file in this virtual drive->select the SP file.

Now I want to install the Office updates that have been released since the last service pack. As there are dozens/hundreds of Office updates that need to be installed, doing this individually for each is not practical. I tried [WSUS Offline](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) but could not get it working in POL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplified process which seems to work.

This is the list of files from the *Wsus Offline Update* software used in the previous instructions. Download these files from the MS website and install them into your Office 2010 POL virtual drive:

- `officesp2010-kb2687455-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe` (if SP2 is not already installed)
- `eqnedt322010-kb4011610-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe`
- `ace2010-kb4462226-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `convloc2010-kb3213626-fullfile-x86-glb`
- `excel2010-kb4464572-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `graph2010-kb4462224-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `onenoteloc2010-kb3114885-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `outlookloc2010-kb4475604-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `proofloc2010-kb3203468-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`
- `visio2010-kb3114872-fullfile-x86-glb.exe` (if you have Visio)
- `wordloc2010-kb4461625-fullfile-x86-glb.exe`

---

**Previous answer**

This ended up being a very manual process with quite a bit of trial and error. Even though there was a message during the installation process saying updates were being installed, I am still unsure if the process below worked and the updates were actually installed.

The general process was:

1. Use a Windows machine (eg on VirtualBox) to [Slipstream Office 2010 setup with SP2](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/slipstreamo2k10sp.htm).
2. Use a Windows machine (eg on VirtualBox) to [download any post-SP2 security updates using wsusoffline.](http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/)
3. Once the individual security updates are downloaded, you will need to extract each one individually and then copy the updates into the `./DVD/Updates` folder from the previous step. This needs to be done in the order of update so that any earlier update files are overwritten by subsequent files with the same name.

   - I used a .bat file in windows to automate this process [based on this script](https://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5479&p=18061&hilit=extract%20msp):
   - `wsusoffline/client/o2k10` seems to contain static downloads, mostly service packs.
   - `wsusoffline/client/ofc`seems to contain dynamic updates for all office versions. I could not figure out how to extract these.
4. Install MS Office 2010 into POL using the Slipstreamed `./DVD/setup.exe`.
5. If you have any issues with activation, try [Andrew Conley's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980370/microsoft-office-2010-on-ubuntu-17-10-wine-connection-error-activation-prob).

Once installed, check your office version number from the MS Word Help menu

- 14.0.4760.1000 = Office 2010 RTM installed
- 114.0.6023.1000 = Office 2010 with SP1
- 14.0.7015.1000 = Office 2010 with SP2
- 14.0.7258.5000 = Office 2020 updated to September 2020

Good luck!