# How to install updates on Microsft Office 2016 installed on PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

How can I install updates to Microsoft Office 2016 installed on Ubuntu 18.04 using PlayOnLinux?

I was able to install [Microsoft Office 2016 using PlayOnLinux (POL)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233780/553502). However clinking Word->`Account`->`Office Updates` does not work in POL. I expect that updates will need to be downloaded and installed manually. It would be good to at least get Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel gets updated.

Comment: I have been facing issues with my other wine applications not being able to connect to the internet a lot, including games (which sucks cause that means that I am restricted to single player). Personally I am satisfied with those apps being able to run (updates are good, don't get me wrong)

Comment: @TimothyWong I previously posted about [manually installing updates for Office 2010](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820317/installing-ms-office-updates-in-playonlinux-wine/987305#987305) and I hope to use a similar process to update Office 2016.